# Create Rect at global coordinate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My scene is 2048 x 1152, and the camera never moves. When I create a rectangle with the following:

```
timeBarRect = new Rect(220, 185, Screen.width / 3, Screen.height / 50);
```

Its position changes depending on the resolution of my game, so I can't figure out how to get it to always land where I want it on the screen. To clarify, if I set the resolution to 16:9, and change the size of the preview window, the game will resize at ratios of 16:9, but the bar will move out from where it's supposed to be.

I have two related questions:

1. Is it possible to place the Rect at a global coordinate?  Since the screen is always 2048 x 1152, if I could just place it at a certain coordinate, it'd be perfect.
2. Is the Rect a UI element?  When it's created, I can't find it in the hierarchy. If it's a UI element, I feel like it should be created relative to a canvas/camera, but I can't figure out a way to do that either.

Update:

I am realizing now that I was unclear about what is actually being visualized. Here is that information:  Once the Rect is created, I create a texture, update the size of that texture in Update() and draw it to the Rect in OnGui():

```
timeTexture = new Texture2D (1, 1);
timeTexture.SetPixel(0,0, Color.green);
timeTexture.Apply();
```

The texture size being changed:

```
void Update () 
    {
        if (time < timerMax) {
            playerCanAttack = false;
            time = time + (10 * Time.deltaTime);
        } else {
            time = timerMax;
            playerCanAttack = true;
        }
```

The actual visualization of the Rect, which is being drawn in a different spot depending on the size of the screen:

```
void OnGUI(){ 
    float ratio = time / 500;
    float rectWidth = ratio * Screen.width / 1.6f;
    timeBarRect.width = rectWidth;
    GUI.DrawTexture (timeBarRect, timeTexture);
}
```

Comment: The `Screen` coordinate system's origin is one of the corners. Are you trying to say that you want it to be the center of the screen?

Comment: The Rect is not a UI element, it's just a data structure that stores 4 floating point numbers. What is this "bar" that you mention, exactly?

Comment: If I could create the Rect at a coordinate relative to the center of the screen, this would solve my problem, yes.  The problem with the current coordinates is that the corner of the screen changes depending on the size of the window.

Comment: @Max: Sorry; I am realizing I was unclear.  After the Rect is created, I draw a texture to it, so that is the actual thing I see when I am talking about the bar being created in a position that changes when I change the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I completely understand either of the two questions I posed, but I did discover that the way to get the rect's coordinates to match the screen no matter what resolution was not using global coordinates, but using the camera's coordinates, and placing code in `Update()` such that the rect's coordinates were updated:

```
timeBarRect.x = cam.pixelWidth / timerWidth;
timeBarRect.y = cam.pixelHeight / timerHeight;
```